# css first element in a child combinator selector

Tags: css

I have such a code:

```
section#secondSite {
    visibility: hidden;
}

section:hover ~ section#secondSite {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and that works. However, I have to be more precise in the first selector because I have 3 main sections. No matter what I try, it doesn't work anymore. For example:

```
section#section1:hover ~ section#secondSite {
section.section1:hover ~ section#secondSite {
.section1:hover ~ section#secondSite {
section[id="section1"]:hover ~ section#secondSite {
```

What I'm doin wrong?

//edit:

here's simplified html:

```
   <section id="container">
<section id="section1"><a href="#secondSite">
<h3>Rehabilitacja domowa</h3>
<hr>
<img src="pliki/fizykoterapia.jpg" alt="fizykoterapia">
Rybnik i okolice
</a>
</section>

    <section>
<h3>Gabinet<br>rehabilitacji</h3>
<hr>
<img src="pliki/fizykoterapia.jpg" alt="fizykoterapia">
    some address data
</section>

    <section>
<h3>Gabinet<br>masażu</h3>
<hr>
<img src="pliki/fizykoterapia.jpg" alt="fizykoterapia">
    some address data
</section>

    </section>         <!-- HERE SECTION CONTAINER ENDS -->

    <!-- SECOND SITE -->

    <section id="secondSite">
<section>
```

Comment: I have, but it's very unreadable since I added microdata xD
Okay, I'm gonna prepare something.

Comment: You have '+' combinator in first place but later one uses '~'. 
Are you sure that '~' works in your UA with dynamic things like :hover ? It may not be supported for performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah, just a typo. I tried both so that's why it remained there. But it should work with ~ I guess. Fixed.

Comment: Works fine on http://jsfiddle.net/s26PT/, so your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Where does #secondSite close?

Comment: Indeed, hell. Maybe some error but "this document was successfully checked as HTML5!" Doesn't work on chrome and firefox. Nah, I'll look into it closer another day :/

Comment: @Moob Here's for your curiosity full code:
http://fizjoterapiarybnik.pl/test/
http://fizjoterapiarybnik.pl/test/style.css
http://fizjoterapiarybnik.pl/test/kolory.css

Comment: It's supposed to display another page on the bottom when you hover over first square but it doesn't.